# Import failed when the module is already in the sys.path

Tags: python, django

It's weird to me that the import fails even when it's in the `sys.path`.

today, I set up a google app engine django environment on ubuntu in my lab's pc. And it works fine when I checked out the code and ran it in windows(same pc in the lab).

But when I went to the dorm, and checked out the code and start to run, it failed weirdly.

I print the `sys.path`, like this:

```
['/home/tower/googlecode/mygae', '/home/tower/googlecode/mygae/.google_appengine', '/home/tower/googlecode/mygae/.google_appengine/lib/antlr3', ...]
```

and when I ran python complained

```
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map
ImportError: No module named appengine.api
```

it's easy to know the google module is in the `'/home/tower/googlecode/mygae/.google_appengine'`
directory, and the`__init__.py` for each module is present.

So what can be the reason for this weird thing? Or what I messed up probably?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you import `google` and `google.appengine`?
Are you sure interpreter has read and traverse access rights to the module tree?

Comment: I've tried. import google is ok. but import google.appengine fails.

I guess maybe google is already in the system's global path, since I try to import google in other places, it succeeds. maybe they collide. 

I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: they truly collided. the google__path__ shows it's in the /var/lib/python-support/python2.6. I'm wondering the import should traverse from the sys.path one by one in order, and if it imports successfully it should stop. But seems import doesn't traverse in the list's order. I should read some docs to know more.

Really thanks. it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on **Ubuntu** when I wanted to play with **google.appengine** in console. First I tried to fix it by removing the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google` package altogether but **Ubuntu One** complained. Finally I resolved it by merging the **GAE SDK google package** into the **package that caused the collision**.

The contents of the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google` dir now look like this:

```
/google
    /appengine
    /net
    /protobuf
    /pyglib
    /storage
    /__init__.py
    /__init__.pyc
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're getting a module (or package) called 'google' from elsewhere -- perhaps `/home/tower/googlecode/mygae` -- and THAT google module has no `appengine` in it. To check, print `google.__file__` and if possible `google.__path__`; that should be informative.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can get an import error for a module when the error is something different, like a syntax error. Try putting

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

just before the import and then s(tep) into the import, and n(ext) thruogh the module in question to see of you get an error.