# GoogleAppEngine and latest Python2.7: location of "google" directory

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

The latest Python2.7 has a `google` directory within `dist-packages`, making it impossible to import the `google` directory which contains `appengine` and other packages from another location. Such directory is required to work to effect imports from GoogleAppEngine (GAE) code on the dev_server. Otherwise such imports fail. An example of such import is:

`from google.appengine.api import mail`

which yields

`ImportError: No module named appengine.api`

This issue is similar to the one in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399896/import-failed-when-the-module-is-already-in-the-sys-path) and indeed following Alex Martelli's [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1400120/1211429) the location of my `google` import is

```
In [1]: import google
In [2]: google.__file__
Out[2]: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/__init__.pyc'
```

rather than the one where I placed the GAE unzipped files.

Any recommended way to fix this? I already thought about *dirty hacks* to fix this, such as putting soft links in the dist-packages google directory, but again, that's *dirty*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages have a special attribute, `__path__`, which tells the Python interpreter where to look for modules and subpackages. By modifying this, you can let Python find contents from both `google` directories. Using the [pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html) module, this ought to work (untested):

```
import pkgutil
import google
google.__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(google.__path__, google.__name__)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I put your code within the `__init__.py` in my `google` directory under `dist-packages`, but the same import error persisted. Am I doing it wrong? If it works it's a really neat way to overcome this prob.

Comment: @JosvicZammit The way I wrote it, you should run that from your own code, before you try and import anything from `google.appengine`. Which `google` directory did you put it in?

Comment: I've put it in the `google` directory under `dist-packages` to no avail, and also tried the code within my own code prior to the import as you suggested, but again didn't work.

Comment: @JosvicZammit What's the value of google.__path__ after executing that statement?

Comment: before `['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google']` and after `['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google']` ... i.e. doesn't change.
P.S. I'm doing this through Django's unit tests management command `python manage.py test` not through `dev_appserver.py`, if that does matter.

Comment: @JosvicZammit Is the SDK in your `sys.path`? What happens if you add the path to the google directory in the SDK to `google.__path__` manually?

Comment: Adding the SDK to `sys.path` manually by `sys.path.append('/home/josvic/dev-tools/google_appengine/')` makes it **work** and pass the test; `google.__path__` becomes: `['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google', '/home/josvic/dev-tools/google_appengine/google']` ... how to best add the SDK path permanently to `sys.path`? By setting PYTHONPATH env variable?

Comment: @JosvicZammit I assumed you had the SDK in the path - it won't work without it, regardless of the existence of another `google` package. The easiest way to add it is to be using the dev_appserver. The next easiest is to use PYTHONPATH, or have your script add it.

Comment: In fact I did suspect it was related, should have pointed it out earlier. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this google directory came with Python 2.7? I've seen it too, but it appeared for the first time when I installed some utility from Google (I think it was Google Storage for Developers).  I also think there's a .pth file related to this.

Comment: Indeed I think it's related to some utility from Google not to Python2.7. However I installed some updates yesterday on Ubuntu 11.10 and the problem started occurring after rebooting. FYI the `google` directory under `dist-packages`, in addition to `__init__.py`, just contains the following directory:
`2012-01-15 18:18 protobuf`

Comment: Check for .pth files in dist-packages or site-packages.

Comment: I'm listing all .pth files under dist-packages:
`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages$ find . -name '*.pth'
./wx.pth
./ubuntuone-storage-protocol.pth
./zope.interface-3.6.1-nspkg.pth
./pygtk.pth
./lazr.restfulclient-0.11.2-nspkg.pth
./ubuntuone-client.pth
./setuptools.pth
./ubuntuone-couch.pth
./ubuntuone-installer.pth
./pygst.pth
./lazr.uri-1.0.2-nspkg.pth
./python-support.pth
./ubuntu-sso-client.pth
./ubuntuone-control-panel.pth
./PIL.pth
./gtk-2.0-pysupport-compat.pth`