# How to resolve a python module import collision?

Tags: python

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399896/import-failed-when-the-module-is-already-in-the-sys-path), but that one doesn't propose a solution.

I have ~/google_appengine/google/appengine and i have /usr/lib64/python2-7/site-packages/google/protobuf.

I can't "import google.appengine" since the other google folder gets in the way. How do i fix this?

Here's a minimal example and error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 12 2012, 13:50:02) 
[GCC 4.5.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google.appengine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named appengine
```

As requested, here's my sys.path:

```
['', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.1.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mock-0.8.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/coverage-3.5.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rosinstall-0.6.11-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/vcstools-0.1.12-py2.7.egg', '/home/murph/google_appengine', '/home/murph/google_appengine/google/appengine', '/home/murph/google_appengine/google', '/home/murph/ros/ros/core/roslib/src', '/usr/lib/portage/pym', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/lib64/portage/pym']
```

And this showing which 'google' it's importing:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 12 2012, 13:50:02) 
[GCC 4.5.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import google
>>> print google.__path__
['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/google']
```

Comment: What's your `sys.path`? Show a minimal code example and error.

Comment: Minimal code example? "import google.appengine" ... "ImportError: No module named appengine."

Comment: Please edit your question to format this stuff appropriately, and put the examples *in your question*.

Comment: You have both ../google_appengine/google/appengine and ../google_appengine/google on your path.  Why not just remove the second one to eliminate the collision and `import appengine` instead of google.appengine?

Comment: I use two different packages that use the appengine, and I'm not free to rewrite their imports. I think that the problem is not that I use both ways there, it's that it's conflicting with "google" from site-packages which only contains the protobuf library.

Comment: Can you install appengine to site-packages/google then?

Comment: No, I'm just a user on this system.

Comment: Can you run pip, or run a virtualenv in your user space?

Comment: Yeah, I could probably do that. Is there just no way to make it work regularly, though? It seems really odd that a system install of protobuf can destroy my appengine installation.

Comment: One dirty hack would be to create a symbolic link to the second one and import it under a different name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a change in the import mecanism since the 2.5 version ( see [this PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports) ) :

`import google` will be for modules in the standard library

For relative

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .google import appengine # (or  from google import appengine)
```

[This blog entry](http://pythonquirks.blogspot.fr/2010/07/absolutely-relative-import.html) explain how to import a relative module.